# resetting connections in neural networks with python

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I have a code that is subclassing `nn.module` .

i don't know what exactly `reset_()` function does and i did not find any `reset_()` function in nn.module source code.

who knows how can i use this for resetting connections in neural networks when there is no operations in that and also there is no function in name `reset_()` in parent class???

```
    class Connection(torch.nn.module):
      super().__init__()

      def reset_(self) -> None:

      #Contains resetting logic for the connection.#

      super().reset_()
```

Comment: what do you mean by reset ? do you mean going back to a former model state with the associated _former_ parameters ? this could be done by re-loading the `state_dict`, more about it here: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/reset-the-parameters-of-a-model/29839 Also, I found this reset() function, but not in nn.module : https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.quasirandom.SobolEngine.reset

Comment: thanks @Blupon ... I mean resetting recordings (of the state variables of connections)  to empty torch.Tensors....in this module(few lines of code) there is no definition for reset_() method and it's only passing .... my question is here why we have to use reset_() function when there is no operations in that....first i thought maybe in nn.Module there is a function is this name but when i checked source code ...i did not find any function with this name....just in another module it was defining reset_() but why it's not importing that module to this code then and it's not calling??

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure what did you mean by `reset()` function in a PyTorch Module, however, usually in many NN layers, there is a `reset_parameters()` function which is used to reset the parameters of that layer. I am giving you an example if it helps.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class Connection(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # a weight matrix of shape [10 x 100] as parameters
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(10, 100))

    def reset_parameters(self) -> None:
        # reset parameters using random values from a uniform distribution
        nn.init.uniform_(self.weight, -0.01, 0.01)


c = Connection()
c.reset_parameters() # reset the weight parameters
```

This is merely an example, you can modify the `reset_parameters` function to fulfill your need.

Comment: thank you @Wasi Ahmad ...it was useful for me even though it's not my answer but helped me to understand more of pytorch:)